# How to mock a Hibernate query using mockito

Tags: mockito, powermockito

I am working on Power mockito for the first time. 
Here is my code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<CurrencyBasedTotalCharges> getCurrencyBasedTotalChargesforCustomerSuperGroupforOperatingAccount(String customerSuperGroupId)
{
    Session session =getSessionFromContext();
    String sql = "SELECT ROUND(SUM(qst),2) ||'`'||ROUND(SUM(pst),2)||'`'||ROUND(SUM(gst),2)||'`'||ROUND(SUM(hst),2)||'`'||ROUND(SUM(converted_val),2)||'`'||currency " +
                 "FROM (" +
                            "SELECT CASE WHEN cr.oper_acc_curr is null or cr.oper_acc_curr='NA'" +
                                    "THEN cr.charge_account_curr" +
                                    "ELSE cr.oper_acc_curr END AS currency," +
                                "nvl ((select case when cr.DR_CR_FLAG='C' then -mcr.value else mcr.value end from mi_charge_record mcr where mcr.original_charge_record_id=cr.reference_id and substr(mcr.charge_code,3,length(mcr.charge_code))='GST'), 0" +
                                "   ) AS gst," +
                                "nvl((select case when cr.DR_CR_FLAG='C' then -mcr.value else mcr.value end from mi_charge_record mcr where mcr.original_charge_record_id=cr.reference_id and substr(mcr.charge_code,3,length(mcr.charge_code))='PST'), 0" +
                                "   ) AS pst," +
                                "nvl((select case when cr.DR_CR_FLAG='C' then -mcr.value else mcr.value end from mi_charge_record mcr where mcr.original_charge_record_id=cr.reference_id and substr(mcr.charge_code,3,length(mcr.charge_code))='QST'), 0" +
                                "   ) AS qst," +
                                "nvl((select case when cr.DR_CR_FLAG='C' then -mcr.value else mcr.value end from mi_charge_record mcr where mcr.original_charge_record_id=cr.reference_id and substr(mcr.charge_code,3,length(mcr.charge_code))='HST'), 0" +
                                "   ) AS hst," + 
                                "CASE WHEN cr.DR_CR_FLAG='C'" +
                                "    THEN (-cr.value) ELSE cr.value END AS converted_val," +
                                "cr.reference_id FROM mi_charge_record cr, mi_bl_billing_preference bp, account acc, customer c," +
                                "mii_customer_group cg"+ 
                            "WHERE acc.account_number=cr.account_number AND acc.customer_id=c.customer_id AND c.customer_group_id=cg.id AND cg.customer_super_group_id=:superGroupId AND" + 
                                    "to_date(cr.BILLED_DATE) BETWEEN to_date(bp.billing_cycle_start_date,'yyyymmdd') AND to_date(bp.billing_cycle_end_date,'yyyymmdd') AND CR.PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME<> 'TAX'" + 
                                    "AND CR.IS_COST <> 'Y'"+
                        ") z" + 
                 "GROUP BY currency having SUM(ROUND(converted_val,2)) != 0";
    List<String> totalchargedetails=session.createSQLQuery(sql).setString("superGroupId", customerSuperGroupId).list();
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> paramMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    paramMap.put(CHARGE_LEVEL, CHARGE_BY_OPERATING_ACCOUNT);
    paramMap.put(LINKED_ENTITY_GUID, customerSuperGroupId);
    paramMap.put(STATEMENT_LEVEL, CUSTOMER_SUPER_GROUP_STATEMENT_LEVEL);
    return getFinalCurrencyBasedTotalCharges(setCurrencyBasedTotalCharges(totalchargedetails),paramMap);
}
```

I am trying to test above functionality using mockito as below:

```
public void getCurrencyBasedTotalChargesforCustomerGroupforOperatingAccountTest() throws Exception
{

    String customerGroupId = "CG-100001-01";

    PowerMockito.doReturn(session).when(implStatementDAOImpl, "getSessionFromContext");
    Mockito.when(query.setString(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(query);
    Mockito.when(session.createQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(query);
    Mockito.doReturn(entityObjectBuilder.currencyBasedTotalCharges()).when(query).list();

    List<String> totalchargedetails = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<CurrencyBasedTotalCharges> test = implStatementDAOImpl.getCurrencyBasedTotalChargesforCustomerGroupforOperatingAccount(customerGroupId);

    //given( implStatementDAOImpl.getCurrencyBasedTotalChargesforCustomerGroupforOperatingAccount(customerGroupId).t, session)).willReturn(new ArrayList<CurrencyBasedTotalCharges>());

    //Assert.assertFalse(test.isEmpty());
    Mockito.verify(session).createQuery(anyString());
    Mockito.verify(query).setString(anyString(), anyString());
    Mockito.verify(query).list();
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

I am getting NullPointer exception on `session.createQuery` line. Plesae guide me how shall I mock this and test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

where is session initialized?

You could do the initialization as follows:

```
@Mock
private Session session;

@Before
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

It is important to init the mocks when using Annotations for mocking/spying

Another option is to init the session like this, e.g directly in your test method:

```
Session session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
```

Comment: Comment or Answer? Please read [how to write an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).